# faster way to loop through two sheets of 10000+ rows

Tags: excel, vba, loops, for-loop

This module goes through each cell in column a in sheet 2, and checks it with every cell in colmumn b in sheet2, if it matchs the "matches number" increases and is placed in a cell im sheet3. the ammount of data is huge and the module keeps on crashing, is there abetter way of doing this (maybe access, or a more efficient VBA module). Please note that I need to know the number of matches for each cell alone and not the total number of repetition.

Thanks in advance fellas!

```
Sub findpatterns()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

Dim RowCount1 As Long, ClmnCount1 As Long
Dim RowCount2 As Long, ClmnCount2 As Long
Dim Crntrow As Long, Lastrow As Long
Dim Crntrow1 As Long, LastRow1 As Long
Dim Recordrow As Long
Recordrow = 1


    RowCount1 = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    ClmnCount1 = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    RowCount2 = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
    ClmnCount2 = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

Lastrow = RowCount1
LastRow1 = RowCount2

Crntrow1 = 1
Crntrow = 1

 For Crntrow1 = 1 To LastRow1
'MsgBox "first loop is running"

For Crntrow = 1 To Lastrow
'MsgBox "second loop is running"
If (Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Crntrow1, "a").Value = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Crntrow, "b").Value Or Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Crntrow, "b").Value = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Crntrow1, "b").Value) And Not Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Crntrow1, "a").Value = "" Then

Sheets("sheet3").Cells(Crntrow1, "b").Value = Sheets("sheet3").Cells(Crntrow1, "b").Value + 1
'Sheets("sheet3").Cells(Crntrow1, "c").Value = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Crntrow1, "g").Value
'MsgBox Material
Else
'MsgBox "no matches found"
End If
Next Crntrow

Next Crntrow1
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off just a few comments on your code as it is not real easy to read.

1. You can get rid of some variables, ClmnCount(1,2) aren't used
2. RowCount(1,2) are only used to pass values directly to Lastrow so you don't really need them
3. By passing RowCount1>LastRow and RowCount2>LastRow1 you make it more confusing try to keep your numbering scheme consistant

It looks like you basically want a countif statement like this

```
=IF(Sheet2!A1="",0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10000,Sheet2!A1)+COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$10000,Sheet2!B1))
```

Which counts the number of occurances in Sheet1 column B that match sheet2 A1 or B1 and does this for each row in column 2 (as long as sheet2 A1 has data in it).

By using this formula in a macro you can avoid the loop using something like the following.  Which uses the formula, fills it down for all the rows you need and then copies the values over the formulas to freeze it.  This should be a fair bit quicker then your double loop.

```
Sub findpatterns()
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

LastRow1 = Sheets("sheet1").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row
LastRow2 = Sheets("sheet2").Cells(Rows.Count, "a").End(xlUp).Row

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1").Formula = "=IF(Sheet2!A1="""",0,COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$" & LastRow1 & ",Sheet2!A1)+COUNTIF(Sheet1!$B$1:$B$" & LastRow1 & ",Sheet2!B1))"
Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1").AutoFill Destination:=Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1:A" & LastRow2)

Calculate

Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1:A" & LastRow2).Value = Sheets("sheet3").Range("A1:A" & LastRow2).Value

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: the first statement will give me the total number of matching so is the second one, I think that i failed to include that i need the number of matches separately for each cell.

Comment: I would just setup the formula in excel like you need it and then put it in vba (if you need to). Watch the quotation marks.  If you need double quotes in the formula it would be 4 quotes.

Answer (score 1):

When you have data that is this large and if it has many columns also, you may want to consider using a database (MSAccess, SQLServer etc).

That said, there are ways to speed up your code also.  Excel objects like Cells, Ranges, Sheets etc are heavy with data about the size, color, borders, fill font etc that you don't likely need.  Try using a variant to store the data ONLY like this:

Let the variable `LastCol` represent the last column in the data.

```
Dim myData as Variant
myData = Range(Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(1, 1), Sheets("Sheet2").Cells(LastRow, LastCol))
```

Note that I did NOT use the `Set` keyword.  This will return the default value for the `Range` object (which is a variant containing only the data.

Now iterating: `For i = LBound(myData, 1) to UBound(MyData, 1)` should be faster.

Comment: @Solaire The important fact that needs to be highlighted is that Excel and VBA interactaions are slow.  This being said, the next step beyond CodeJockey's optimization is to store the data from Column B in Sheet3 in an array in VBA, and only paste it when you are done.

Comment: will this method give me the number of matches for each cell or the total number of matches. sorry if the question is too stupid but arrays kind of confuse me.

Comment: You can write it to do whatever you like, including counting the number of matches.  The only difference is now you will use `myData(curntRow, 2)` instead of `sheets.cells(curntRow, "b")`

Comment: Thanks Im currently trying to use arrays in my code