# Excel VBA - A faster way to loop through a bunch of Range.Finds

Tags: performance, vba, excel

I'm performing a 'join-like' operation (analogous to a database) in which I have two distinct datasets A and B with some identifier in common (let's call this the 'id'). My objective is to create a third dataset C which consists of the intersection of A and B (joining on id). In SQL the corresponding query would be something like

```
SELECT a.id, a.some_column, b.another_column 
FROM a,b 
WHERE a.id = b.id
```

I'm able to do the same in Excel by looping over all the rows in A's id column and doing a `Range.Find` over B's id column for each row in A. Something like this:

```
For Each r in Worksheet_A.Range(Cells(start_row_a,id_column_a),Cells(end_row_A,id_column_a))
    Set found = Worksheet_B.Range(Cells(start_row_b,id_column_b),Cells(end_row_b,id_column_b)).Find(r.Value)
    If Not found is Nothing Then
        ' write stuff to Worksheet_C, e.g. found.Value, found.Offset(0,1).Value, r.Offset(0,-1).Value, etc.
    End If
Next r
```

This works fine, but it's pretty slow. I'm aware that explicit loops in languages like VB are quite slow. My question is: is there a fasterway? Have I missed a much better implementation? The closest question I could find on SO is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25852657/faster-way-to-loop-through-two-sheets-of-10000-rows), but I don't really understand the best answer, and I'm not sure whether it's applicable to my scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You try to use [ADO (*ActiveX Data Object*)](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257819).
This will allow you to use simple SQL statements as in your example.

Sample:

```
Sub ject()
    Dim con As Object: Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Dim rec As Object: Set rec = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Dim datasource As String
    datasource = "C:\Users\user.name\Desktop\TestFolder\Test.xlsx" 'change to suit

    Dim sconnect As String
    'Connection string used is for Excel 2007 and up
    sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
                "Data Source=" & datasource & ";" & _
                "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES"";"
    con.Open sconnect

    Dim sqlstr As String

    sqlstr = "SELECT e.column1, u.column2, e.column3, e.column4 "
    sqlstr = sqlstr & "FROM [A$] e " 'from a sheet named A
    sqlstr = sqlstr & "INNER JOIN [B$] u " 'compare with a sheet named B
    sqlstr = sqlstr & "ON e.id = u.id " 
    sqlstr = sqlstr & "GROUP BY e.column1, u.column2, e.column3, e.column4 "

    rec.Open sqlstr, con, 3, 1

    Dim lrow As Long
    With Sheets("C") 'Change to suit
        .Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset rec
    End With

    rec.Close: con.Close
    Set rec = Nothing: Set con = Nothing
End Sub
```

This method maybe a bit new to you but I'm sure works and it sure is fast 
 (although I have not actually compared the speed).
To know about connection strings for [XL 2003 and below](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2003/) and [XL 2007 and up](http://www.connectionstrings.com/excel-2007/) check the links.
Btw, you can set the data source into the same workbook where you run the macro.

**Example:**

```
datasource = ThisWorkbook.FullName
```

where you have Sheets **A** and **B** and another Sheet **C** for the output. HTH.

Answer (score 0):

The most significant way to speed up this sort of thing is to know that interactions between the "VBA world" and the "Worksheet world" are slow, so you should keep them to a minimum.

So you should refactor your code like this:

1. swallow the entire WorksheetA table into an array
2. swallow the entire WorksheetB table into an array
3. do your for-cycle work as you have now, but over those arrays, and writing into a third array
4. drop the entire third array into a worksheet

This is done using variant arrays as documented here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff726673.aspx#xlFasterVBA

in the section labeled: Read and Write Large Blocks of Data in a Single Operation

Refactoring is easier than it seems, because arrays also take row and column coordinates, just like the original sheets.

Of course you could have memory problems if your tables are too big, but with today's RAM sizes, they would have to be really, really huge to be a problem...